# pregnancy- fallout shelter

Tags: fallout-shelter

I am playing fallout shelter and one of my women is pregnant. It has been a few hours now but she still has not given birth? i do not know what to do? I have tried to upgrade the room incase I did not have anough room that id not work. I do not know whether it is because she is radiated. I am just not sure.